# Convert HTML Dom to string in PHP

Tags: php

An HTML DOM Contains characters such as id="xyz" or class:'col-md-3'. The problem is I have a PHP script which converts PHP variable to strings. But one of my variable contains HTML dom elements. I am having a hard time to convert that variable into a string.

My code:

```
 foreach($result as $n){

$message1 = '"'.(string)$n['Message'].'"';
$message = "'".(string)addslashes($message1)."'";

{
```

error:

```
/><br /><table style=\'border:1px solid...
                             ^ - error 1
AT <span id="cat_id"
            ^ - error 2
",\"
  ^ -error 3
```

Comment: i hope `$n['Message']` is coming as  a string itself. So why converting to string and using `addslashes()`?

Comment: yes it coming as a string but in the html dom there is an id tag i.e. id="xyz". The double quotes is throwing error which I think is clashing with it

Comment: Why are you wrapping your input data in double quotes, then single quotes anyhow?!?  What are you doing with `$message` next?  emailing? building an sql query?

Comment: I am getting confuse because in the Message1 variable a html dom is passing by, and it has both double quotes aswell as single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not what you really want to achieve but something like below could help I guess.

```
$message = "'".(string)addslashes('"'.$messag1.'"')."'";
echo $message;
```